# why rvalue reference can be bind to a non reference type

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

```
int main()
{
    int rx = 0;
    int ry = std::move(rx); //here is the point of my question

    int lx = 0;
    int ly = &lx; //(2) obviously doesn't compile

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

I'm a little bit lost with this aspect of rvalue, I can't understand how we can't bind &&rx to ry, because std::move(rx) is a reference to a rvalue, so I believed that this kind of expression could only be bind to a reference type as is it he case for lvalue reference and illustrated in (2)

Comment: Not "bind", "copy". You are also confusing references and pointers (`&lx` is a pointer).

Comment: It's move construction. Just like `A a = some_a` calling the copy constructor, it calls the move constructor.

Comment: I have auto voted to close it, I don"t like my question much longer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References != address-of operator.

```
int& ly = lx; // reference
int* ly = &lx; // pointer
```

Answer (score 2):

> std::move obtains an rvalue reference to its argument and converts it to an xvalue. [[1]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

Which in turn can be copied to `ry`.

The expression `int ry = std::move(rx);` does not "bind" `rx` to `ry`. It tells the compiler that `rx` is no longer needed and that its contents can be moved to `ry` while at the same time invalidating `rx`.

This is especially useful when functions return by value:

```
std::vector<int> foo() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};
    return v;
}
std::vector<int> u = foo();
```

At `return v` the compiler notice that v is no longer needed an that it can actually use it directly as `u` without doing a deep copy of the vector contents.